# How to resume a session on Facebook Connect iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook, session, resume

I'm using Facebook Connect for the iPhone in one of our applications.
When the user logs in using FBLoginDialog, we pass the iPhone's session_secret to the server and our server then has access to all of facebook's functionality.

However, when we use [session resume], even though it returns true, [session isConnected] returns true and we're getting a session_secret, all of our Facebook calls fail as if we weren't logged on to Facebook.

What is the correct way to use [session resume] in Facebook Connect for the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the simulator, be careful about being logged in to Facebook in Safari, which shares cookies and such with the simulated Mobile Safari.  Emptying Safari's cache fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

We have developed one class that simplify the original Facebook Connect, creating one single session object that persist on all your applications objects. Also giving to you simple methods to execute simple tasks as login, logout and publish feeds.

One example is to implement a simple login, just call the login method on your session object:

```
[fbsession login];
```

This code will open a Facebook Connect dialog and ask your user for the login and password. If the login is sucessfull, all information about this session will be stored and easily acessible on any point of your application.

You can download and see all the documentation here: http://code.google.com/p/fbconnectsession/wiki/About